# UISlider in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to connect a text field with a slider. I want the slider to list numbers from 1-100 or 1-1000. I've looked places but there is no true answer to what I'm looking for. Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;      
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;

- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) changeButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @implementation TutorialProjectViewController

    @synthesize mySlider, myTextField;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextField.delegate = self;

    }

    - (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
        myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];
    }

    - (IBAction) changeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        NSString *textValue = [myTextField text];
        float value = [textValue floatValue];
        if (value < 0) value = 0;
        if (value > 100) value = 100;
        mySlider.value = value;
        myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", value];

    }

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    //[put your textfield name here resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

    @end
```

Change Slider Value:

[image]

Comment: I had a couple things pop up. First when i put in the name of my text field, it made me change it to put the _ in front of it. Also, it made me change the Slider.value to UISlider.value. and then there are 2 bugs. It says expected identifier on the line UISlider.value = [[myTextBox.text] intValue]; and it also says that the property 'value' not found on object of type 'UISlider'

Comment: I had a couple things pop up. First when i put in the name of my text field, it made me change it to put the _ in front of it. Also, it made me change the Slider.value to UISlider.value. and then there are 2 bugs. It says expected identifier on the line UISlider.value = [[myTextBox.text] intValue]; and it also says that the property 'value' not found on object of type 'UISlider' @Programmer...

Comment: Ok ive done everything. Now when I go to type in a number, or press anything on the keyboard, the app immediately crashes... also I want the numbers to go by 1's and go from 0-1000... i cant figure out how to change that

Comment: Now the only problem left is when i press the Done button on the keyboard, the app crashes.. But i got everything else to work.. whats the deal?

Comment: I did the new code... still isn't working though... What did you mean by "drag textField (mainstoryboard) on all the textfields to hide the keyboard"... Not sure why this isnt working @Programmer...

Comment: [textField resignFirstResponder]; In the textield section of the code write your textfield name (in the code I provided it would be myTextField) ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to update the text field's text as the slider is changed.

You don't connect the two. You need to listen for changes to the slider's value. In the method that you setup for this, you need to convert the slider's value to the text you want. You then update the text field's text with this new text based on the slider's value.

The hook for the slider:

```
[someSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderUpdate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The method that listens to the slider:

```
- (void)sliderUpdate:(UISlider *)slider {
    float newVal = slider.value;

    NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)newVal];

    someTextField.text = newText;
}
```

This code assumes the slider is referenced in the `someSlider` ivar and the text field is referenced by the `someTextField` ivar. It also assumes the slider's `minimumValue` is 0 and the `maximumValue` is 100 or 1000 as needed.

Comment: ya actually I haven't done any of that. I seriously need like all the details. I'm pretty new to all this stuff

Comment: ya actually I haven't done any of that. I seriously need like all the details. I'm pretty new to all this stuff @Programmer...

Comment: ya actually I haven't done any of that. I seriously need like all the details. I'm pretty new to all this stuff @rmaddy

Comment: @trludt One comment is enough. No need to spam.

Comment: Sorry the only reason i did that was cause i forgot to tag.. and i was afraid you wouldnt see. sorry, I'm new to all this @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy i am using this code - (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)sender { slider.value = [sender.text floatValue]; }    - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

     }

Comment: @Programmer... You have the accepted answer. I'm curious why you are asking me. I thought the question was for the other direction (change the text as the slider is moved). But yes, I would have no trouble updating a slider from a text field if needed. I haven't followed this question since I posted my answer. It looks like chaos to me. :)

Comment: @trludt had an question on that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextBox;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleOnTop;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeButtonPressed:(id)sender;


@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize mySlider, myTextBox;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextBox.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    myTextBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [sender value]];
}

- (void)sliderUpdate:(UISlider *)slider {
    float newVal = slider.value;

    NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)newVal];

    myTextBox.text = newText;
}


- (IBAction) changeButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *textValue = [myTextBox text];
    float value = [textValue floatValue];
    if (value < 0) value = 0;
    if (value > 1000) value = 1000;
    mySlider.value = value;
    myTextBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", value];
    if ([myTextBox canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    if (myTextBox)
    {
        if ([myTextBox canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

/*
 // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView {
 }
 */


/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.username = self.myTextBox.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.username;
    if ([nameString length] == 0) {
        nameString = @"World";
    }
   }

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: When i open the keyboard to type in a number.. it works. but when i press the 'Done' Button, app crashes... NO IDEA WHY ITS KILLING ME! @Programmer...

Comment: - (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event delete this code section I think it the issue....

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
} delete this code and tell me if the keyboard is still crashing

Comment: ya i added return NO; before the line return YES; and then i also deleted that section.. still crashing for some reason @Programmer...

Comment: Delete the return YES and only put return NO

Comment: When i deleted the (BOOL) section of code, when i pressed the 'Done' button, the keyboard did not go away

Comment: Do you think i need to change the part where it says (UITextField *)?? @Programmer...

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
} Try this piece of code :)

Comment: - (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    if (myTextBox)
    {
        if ([myTextBox canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
} Delete this code and add this code - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField { [myTextBox resignFirstResponder]; return NO; }

Comment: Are you doing it with the return NO

Comment: Yes. Does it matter where i put these sections in the code? cause my      -(BOOL) section is at the very end of my code. @Programmer...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgnRjp1ZEkY watch this video to hide the keyboard....

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextBox.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

Comment: Write this code in your project  
- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; self.myTextBox.delegate = self; } - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField { [myTextBox resignFirstResponder]; return NO; }

Comment: Ok I figured it out! I had to create 2 more - (IBAction) sections of code. And in the storyboard, i had to delete the connection with the text box and the (IBAction)changeButtonPressed:(id)sender section.. so i'm still kind of confused.. and then also i wanted to know if you knew how to get the slider to change towards the number i typed into the text. For example, if the slider is all the way to the left, and i type in 500. I want the slider to move to the middle when i press done... you know how to do that? @Programmer...

Comment: Yes! haha finally. I was able to get the keyboard to go away when i touched the background or when i touched the 'Done' button! The only issue left is what i said in my above comment ^^^ @Programmer...

Comment: Try this code: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:numberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    BOOL basicTest = [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    if (basicTest) {
        slider.value = [aleField.text floatValue];
    }
    return basicTest;
}

Comment: Or this:                                                             After creating your textfield, add:

[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
Then have the following method:

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)sender {
    //Assuming slider is a property
    slider.value = [sender.text floatValue];
}

Comment: ok i did. and where would i put in the second option? where would i put that code? @Programmer...

Comment: Put it in FirstViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

```
  #import "FirstViewController.h"

    @interface FirstViewController ()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextBox;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleOnTop;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
    - (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)changeButtonPressed:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;


    @end

    @implementation FirstViewController

    @synthesize mySlider, myTextBox;

    - (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
    {
        [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
    {
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.myTextBox.delegate = self;
    }

    - (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
    {
        myTextBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [sender value]];
    }

    - (void)sliderUpdate:(UISlider *)slider {
        float newVal = slider.value;

        NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)newVal];

        myTextBox.text = newText;
    }

  - (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)sender { slider.value = [sender.text floatValue]; } 

    - (IBAction) changeButtonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        NSString *textValue = [myTextBox text];
        float value = [textValue floatValue];
        if (value < 0) value = 0;
        if (value > 1000) value = 1000;
        mySlider.value = value;
        myTextBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", value];
        if ([myTextBox canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
    {
        if (myTextBox)
        {
            if ([myTextBox canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
        }
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
    }

    /*
     // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
     - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
     // Custom initialization
     }
     return self;
     }
     */

    /*
     // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
     - (void)loadView {
     }
     */



     // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

     }



    /*
     // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
     - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
     }
     */


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

        self.username = self.myTextBox.text;

        NSString *nameString = self.username;
        if ([nameString length] == 0) {
            nameString = @"World";
        }
       }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [myTextBox resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }


    @end
```